# How to setup a query to output posts by groups of five?

Tags: posts, loop, query

I'd like to have a query that returns posts grouped five by five.

Right now I have a simple query loop like this one :

```
<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <ul class="posts">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </li> 
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It outputs :

```
<ul class="posts">
    <li>post 1</li>
    <li>post 2</li>
    <li>post 3</li>
    <li>post 4</li>
    <li>post 5</li>
    <li>post 6</li>
    <li>post 7</li>
    <li>post 8</li>
    <li>post 9</li>
    <li>post 10</li>
</ul>
```

Instead, what I'd like to have is :

```
<ul class="posts">
    <li>post 1</li>
    <li>post 2</li>
    <li>post 3</li>
    <li>post 4</li>
    <li>post 5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="posts">
    <li>post 6</li>
    <li>post 7</li>
    <li>post 8</li>
    <li>post 9</li>
    <li>post 10</li>
</ul>
```

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a simple counter and condition:

```
 <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <ul class="posts">
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            if ($count < 5){ 
                ?>
                <li>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </li> 
                <?php
            }else{
                echo '</ul><ul class="posts">';         
            ?>
                <li>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </li> 
                <?php
                $count = 0;
            }
            $count = $count + 1;
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hehe!! You beat me by seconds. :)

Comment: that creates a group of five only for the first five posts. I'm trying to make groups of five for any number of posts.

Comment: @mike23, my bad , i added a better solution, which simply counts to 5 each time and if you want to change the number just change 5 to whatever you want

Comment: actually your solution works better.

Comment: @mike23, glad i could help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <ul class="posts">
        <?php $count = 0; ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </li> 
        <?php 
           $count++; 
           if ( ( $count % 5 ) == 0 && $query->have_posts() ) {
        ?>
    </ul>
    <ul class="posts">
        <?php
           }
        endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: sometimes a last empty item (<ul></ul>) is created. For example if you have 9 posts and show groups of 3 (`$count % 3`), it actually creates 4 groups, three filled with the posts and one empty one at the end. Do you have an idea how to fix that ?

Comment: check now, its fixed